# When and why does Not implemented (java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException) occur?

Tags: java, eclipse, jform-designer

While opening a JFD file in Eclipse, I am got 'Not implemented (java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException)'. Can you tell me when and why does it occur?

Answer (score 1):

It means that a method you are calling throws that exception, and you are not doing anything about it. You either need to put the method call in a try/catch block, or you need to re-throw the exception for someone else to handle.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, which method? It's not occurring as a result of any unimplemented java method. It is happening when I am trying to open a JFD file.